# Jobs falling apart

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

No really it is...the tabs are now right aligned.  Tags have fallen out of their placeholders.

[image]

Unit testing and quality assurance at its finest!

Comment: It's the Apocalypse! The end-times! I always knew Craver would be the one responsible for it.

Comment: @Shog9 - Wheres the quality assurance?

Comment: Jon, QA would reduce the number of bugs you are able to find! Are you trying to make your work here obsolete? :)

Comment: @PetahChristian: It's not like he gets paid for it anyway :( (Or does he...)

Comment: @BoltClock - I signed a contract with SO for each bug I find it is equivalent to a thread being sewn on a new shiny SO t-shirt.  So I work for clothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

The problem was found and corrected. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Poor Nick, too much is on his hands.

Comment: @JonH Mouse, ring, band-aid.