# All icons are the same

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I am not sure if this a bug or not but all of my icons are the same.

[image: Pic][image: PIc]

Comment: Reported on MSE - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/meta-stack-exchanges-logo-shows-up-as-3d

Comment: But don't delete it as otherwise someone else will only post it.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've just deleted mine :D

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319884/jobs-falling-apart

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks for the image resize!

Comment: I'll just leave this [here](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/714446403548872704).

Comment: @JaredBurrows No problem. You just need to append "m" before the image extension.

Comment: The real question is why 3D and not SE

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that it just happened to be the first community in the list. WorldBuilding is probably planning on becoming 1World now.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I think money changed hands.  Those 3d printer manufacturers, and their underhanded lobbying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and Nick Craver answered on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277530/164200) with details but for those who don't want to click a link, this happened because:

> The build mitigation in place we had (to not remove the old files) didn't stick correctly in the production build, and a robocopy mirror wiped them out - a fix to the pathing is rolling out now. I'm building out now to resolve the favicons and /jobs issues - we're taking a look at the chat issue as well.