# 3D Printing site icon on every site

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not sure how relevant this is with the [developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing?cb=1) coming up but all the site icons on my CV are from [3D Printing](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com).

[image: CV page]

Comment: Duplicate question on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/all-stack-exchange-site-logos-are-showing-up-as-the-3d-printing-one).

Comment: Same here. Probably related to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319886/all-icons-are-the-same

Comment: @Glorfindel While probably related, that question doesn't mention Jobs CV, and is marked as resolved.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously related to yesterday's network-wide issue..

Comment: @cybermonkey: what issue are you talking about?

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ The entire SE network was down for a couple of minutes https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/714446403548872704

Comment: ^^ Oh okay. I get it.