# Everything is 3D

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I think something is wrong with the panel, look:

[image]

Is it only me or something went bad?

Comment: The sites are 3D now? Does SE provide 3D glasses, or can they give us a list of preferred providers? Can't wait to get a question thrown at me!

Comment: It's also showing up in front of all the hot network questions, though not on Meta oddly.

Comment: For the sake of reference, I can reproduce this on Chrome 55.0.2883.75 running on Windows 10.

Comment: And the site is rev 2016.12.6.4298.

Comment: seems like a CSS issue on the original SO. The tool-tips are okay though.

Comment: That's why I don't like sprites. 3D is the [first favicon](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=41af8148f8e0).

Comment: I feel like this has happened before.

Comment: [8 months ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319886/all-icons-are-the-same).

Comment: @ryanyuyu [and all of this will happen again](https://youtu.be/6bOy3RNyWME).

Comment: I'm watching history repeat itself.

Comment: The 3D logo is also showing for the "Meta User" and "Network Profile" links on the user profile page.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I'm having the exact same problem. It's not just you.

Comment: At least the '3D Printing' icon is correct... as for the others, I didn't know Stack Exchange 3D™ rolled out this early.

Comment: This actually makes browsing the hot network questions a lot more interesting. Take "How do I include photos in blender?": could be Photography, but sounds more like a handy Life Hack!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was trying to make the site fully https:// and 3D at the same time, but obviously you people just can't handle that much awesome. So I'm rolling out a <s>bufgix</s> awesomeness reversion now.

Comment: Would be a good gag for April Fools (with a few extra bits) next year though... also provide a template for 3D glasses that don't need lenses (they use Magic™).

Comment: we can call it project StackOverHolo

Comment: Extra points for "bufgix."

Comment: Does this mean SO is now 100% SSL?

Comment: @DavidG getting there. We still need to eliminate mixed content in places, but I'm working on moving lots of stuff around to support it. meta.*.stackexchange.com is major, and we're moving huge things to make that move possible and smooth.

Comment: @NickCraver Awesome, I know this is a massive task having read some of your blog and a rather amusing exchange on Reddit :)